# three. scene is not a function

Tags: html, three.js

I'm using three.js and the attached code is returning the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: THREE.Scene is not a function
>
> init @ new 1.html:18

on this line

`scene=new THREE.Scene();`

What could be causing this and how can I go about fixing it?

```
window.onload = init

var scene, camera, render;

function init() {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 200); //перспективная проекция
    camera.position.y = 150;
    camera.position.z = 500;

    var line_geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    line_geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    line_geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Verctor3(0, 40, 50));

    var line = new THREE.Line(line_geometry);

    scene.add(line);

    render = new THREE.WebGLRender(); //рендеринг
    render = setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); //инициализация рендеринга

    container.appendChild(render.domElement); //??
    render.render(scene);

}
```

Here is a screen shot of the error.

[image]

Comment: container=document.createElement('div'); did you forget the var?

Comment: thats not help,
my trouble in "three. scene is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

You have many typos in your code:
`Verctor3` instead of `Vector3`
`WebGLRender` instead of `WebGLRenderer`
`render.render(scene);` instead of `render.render(scene, camera);`
and so on.
Also you should just run `init()` at start instead of `window.onload=init`.

Generally - please refer to [this](http://threejs.org/examples/) page. There are many working examples there.